# Format Pandas Dataframe from 2D Array

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, matrix

I have a problem where I am taking a 2D array and want to convert it to a pandas Dataframe. I will be taking this Dataframe and displaying in an excel spreadsheet.

I created my Dataframe like this: `df = pd.DataFrame("twoDArray")`. The 2D array I am transforming into a Dataframe is of length 8, and I named all the columns using the following code,
`df.columns = ["column1", column2", "column3", "column4", "column5", "column6", "column7", "column8"]`

The Nested arrays are very long, and **not** always the same length. I want the nested arrays at each index to be an entire column on the Dataframe. So one row would be `lst[0][0], lst[1][0], lst[2][0]`.

**example**:

Pandas seems to do this by default

```
    lst = [["hello", 1],["World", 3], ["Goodbye" , 5]]
    df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
         
   output:    
              column1   column2
    1        hello           1
    2        World           3
    3        Goodbye         5
```

but I want:

```
   lst = [["hello", 1, 2], ["World", 3], ["Goodbye", 5,6,7,"test"]]
   df = pd.DataFrame(lst)

     output:
           column1  column2 column3
    1       hello    World  Goodbye
    2           1        3        5
    3           2        -        6
    4           -        -        7
    5           -        -     test
```

Is this possible to do?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: try this: `df = pd.DataFrame(lst).T`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code solves your question:

```
lst = [["hello", 1, 2], ["World", 3], ["Goodbye", 5,6,7,"test"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst).T
```

Because the `.T` represents transposing the dataframe, which is what you were trying to do, instead of your lists being rows, they should be columns, and the remaining values are NaN